# How can I disable tls/crypto on apache 2.4, php 8, sendmail, typo3 11 with local mail exchange server?

Tags: apache, ssl, smtp, typo3

These are my settings:
sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server = 10.1.xxx.xxx
smtp_port=25
smtp_ssl=none
```

php.ini

```
[mail function]
SMTP = 10.1.xxx.xxx
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_path = "C:\Webserver\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
```

Typo3

```
'MAIL' => [
    'defaultMailFromAddress' => 'noreply@domain.org',
    'defaultMailFromName' => 'Domain',
    'transport' => 'smtp',
    'transport_sendmail_command' => '',
    'transport_smtp_encrypt' => false,
    'transport_smtp_password' => '',
    'transport_smtp_server' => '10.1.xxx.xxx:25',
    'transport_smtp_username' => '',
],
```

SSL certificate is provided by a netscaler configuration

Typo3 Test Mail Setup
**Could not deliver mail**
Please verify $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['MAIL'][*] settings are valid.
Error message: Unable to connect with STARTTLS: stream_socket_enable_crypto():
Peer certificate CN=`*.domain.de' did not match expected CN=`10.1.xxx.xxx'

Answer (score 0):

Ehm, with `transport_smtp_encrypt=false` the connection will be tried via STARTTLS. For using an SSL-Connection, `transport_smtp_encrypt` has to be `true`.

[Important: #91070 - SMTP transport option ‘transport_smtp_encrypt’ changed to boolean](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.4.x/Important-91070-SMTPTransportOptionTransport_smtp_encryptChangedToBoolean.html)

Comment: so there is no chance to deactivate encryption as false uses Starttls and true ssl - thanks for the information

Answer (score 0):

> so there is no chance to deactivate encryption as false uses Starttls and true ssl - thanks for the information

@alexinge I think STARTTLS is only used if the server that you try to connect to is able to handle it. As the [changelog of version 4.4 of symfony/mailer](https://github.com/symfony/mailer/blob/4.4/CHANGELOG.md) says (highlight by me):

> - STARTTLS cannot be enabled anymore (it is used automatically if TLS is disabled **and the server supports STARTTLS**)

So you might try to change the configuration of the mail server (if you have access to that) or maybe use another port (**587** with `'transport_smtp_encrypt' => false` or **465** with `'transport_smtp_encrypt' => true`).